# How can i add conditional statements in Regex

Tags: regex

I have 2 strings

```
1) abc-def 
2) abc-
```

and i have written regex group `(?<Myid>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)` all works fine for the first string

However in 2nd string i don't need "-", only `abc` should be selected. How can i add condition here.

Comment: `(?<Myid>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\b`, `(?<Myid>[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])`

Comment: in given example is "abc" stands for Myid?

Comment: @hiteshbedre It is `abc-def` (String #1) and `abc-` (String #2) that will be captured in the `Myid` group. The problem is with the second string only, it must capture ``abc``, not ``abc-``.

Comment: Yes, but I think Tim's solution is also working for you.

Comment: Can I aks why did you select hitesh's answer? Do you mean you want to match any char at the end even if it is not alphanumeric (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/MGo5yU/1))? Note that only Tim's answer contains the solution, it is even more efficient than those in my top comment.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew in Myid group i want to negate '-' if it is at the end and there are characters after that i want it to work the way it is, i agree Tim answer also works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just appending the negation rule at the end will suffice here I guess.

i.e. `(?<Myid>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+[^-])`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/PetK6Q/1

Comment: Note that `[^-]` matches any char other than `-`. `§`, `Ф`, `Æ`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I would phrase your regex as:

```regex
(?<Myid>[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)
```

This pattern says to match:

```regex
[a-zA-Z0-9]+        match one or more alphanumeric characters
(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*  followed by dash and more alphanumeric characters,
                    zero or more times
```

### Demo

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I guess it depends on the context in which the regex is being used.  For example, Java's `String#matches` implicitly would add `^` and `$` anchors, thereby making adding them in my answer superfluous.